# How do I update every single row in a specific table with PHP?

Tags: mysql, php

I want to edit/change the value of a specific column value with PHP. For example, let's say that I have thousands of records and I want to change every record's column value to 1. How would I do this in PHP?

```
<?php
$id='rank';
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="python_crawler";
$host="localhost";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

$query=" SELECT * FROM url WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,'1');
++$i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Follow a PHP/MySQL tutorial. Use an `update` statement without a `where` clause.

Comment: Really didn't help me, I've already looked for one.

Comment: Well, what have you done and where in the process are you stuck?

Comment: Updated, I'm getting an error. mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 11

Comment: Noah, please review your previous questions and accept correct answers where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_close();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,'1');
```

Don't close your connection before you fetch your results. You need to not have the mysql_close() until you're done with your database connection.

```
$query="UPDATE url SET someColumn = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

$result is a boolean (true / false) on update statements.

Finally, if you're taking user input anywhere, be aware that you've set yourself up for SQL injection. Read up on [using mysqli and binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). At this point, it's kind of the fault of PHP that this isn't what the tutorial is, but that's the way of the world.